# If/ Else, test true first or false first

Tags: performance, optimization, conventions

I have a rather specific question.

Say I am at the end of a function, and am determining whether to return true or false.

I would like to do this using an if/else statement, and have two options: (examples are in pseudocode)

1) Check if worked first:

```
if(resultVar != error){
    return true;
}else{
    return false;
}
```

2) Check if it failed first:

```
if(resultVar == error){
    return false;
}else{
    return true;
}
```

**My question is simple: Which case is better (faster? cleaner?)?**

I am really looking at the if/else itself, disregarding that the example is returning (but thanks for the answers)

The function is more likely to want to return true than false.

I realize that these two cases do the exact same thing, but are just 'reversed' in the order of which they do things. I would like to know if either one has any advantage over the other, whether one is ever so slightly faster, or follows a convention more closely, etc.

I also realize that this is extremely nitpicky, I just didn't know if there is any difference, and which would be best (if it matters).

**Clarifications:**

A comparison needs to be done to return a boolean. The fact that of what the examples are returning is less relevant than how the comparison happens.

Comment: Why not `return resultVar != error;`? No need for an `if` at all.

Comment: Best to let the compiler/optimizer worry about things like that and write code that is the most clear to you and the folks that will maintain it later. Your minor changes could very well be re-organized by the optimizer anyway, and thus be irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only difference in both examples may be the implementation of the operator.  A != operator inverses the operation result.  So it adds an overhead, but very small one.  The == is a straight comparison.

But depending on what you plan to do on the If/else, if there is simply assigning a value to a variable, then the conditional ternary operator (?) is faster.  For complex multi value decisions, a switch/case is more flexible, but slower.

This will be faster in your case:

```
return (resultVar == error) ? false : true;
```

Comment: I am not familiar to this syntax, what languages do this?

Comment: @Snappawapa At least C, C++, Java, and C#.

Comment: Edited my answer, because forgot the return.  You can get more information here: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/operators/

Comment: @zenith interesting. I will have to look into this.

Comment: @Snappawapa FWIW, it's called [_the ternary operator_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:).

Comment: Just wanted to point out that `!=` may or may not actually swap it in assembly. When I was learning MIPS assembly, I believe there was both an `equal` `EQ` check and a `not equal` `NEQ` check. Because of that, one was not faster than the other.

Answer (score 6):

This is by far the cleanest:

```
return resultvar != error;
```

Answer (score 2):

This will depend entirely on the language and the compiler. There is no specific answer. In C for instance, both of these would be encoded rather like:

```
return (resultVar!=error);
```

by any decent compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Put true first, because it potentially eleiminates a `JUMP` command in assembly. However, the difference is negligible, since it's an `else`, rather than an `else if`. There may /technically be a difference/, but you will see no performance difference in this case.